# Java client and InstanceContextMode

Tags: java, wcf

I have an application consisting of WCF service and several clients, all made in .NET (C#).
Now I need to add another client, it has to be in Java, and I don't have much experience there.
So I am experimenting a bit now, and almost immediately have met a problem.

My service behaviour is [InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single]. The logic in service is based on fact that subsequent calls in the same session are handled by the same service object.

But for Java client it doesnt work, new service object is created for each call from client. I don't really want to change service, and I guess there should be a way to keep the session alive from Java, but I can't find any advices in web that I can apply.

I am using Eclipse (Juno Service Release 2), and client code is generated using WSDL file.

Here is the code I use to test client:

```
IMDReceiverProxy proxy = new IMDReceiverProxy("http://localhost:25001/MDSS");
Greeting msg = new Greeting("HTTP", "javaWsTest);
proxy.acceptGreeting(msg);
proxy.acceptGreeting(msg);//oops, new service object created
```

Comment: The problem is BasicHttpBinding, it does not support sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is BasicHttpBinding, it does not support sessions.